# valueForKey: on packed struct?

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct

Given the following packed struct:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    BOOL flag;
    int x;
} Foo;
```

And the following class:

```
@interface Obj : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) Foo foo;
@end

@implementation Obj
@end
```

Trying to call `valueForKey:` on a property which has type of packed struct:

```
Obj *obj = [Obj new];
id boo = [obj valueForKey:@"foo"];
```

causes a crash inside `valueForKey:` (actually it's crashing not inside `valueForKey:` but in random places depending on moon magnitude, I guess it's memory corruption).

If I remove `__attribute__((packed))` it works fine.
Any possibility to get struct's data without a crash? Is it Apple's bug?

PS. I do need to do it at runtime, i.e. I can't just call `.foo` directly, I only have `@"foo"` string at runtime. (What I'm trying to achieve actually is to recursively print object contents).

Comment: "Is it Apple's bug?" That sounds rather likely.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid KVO for your usage case, and stick to the handy dandy `<objc/runtime.h>` header. You can re-implement a basic part of KVO using this kind of introspection. Struct packing is used primarily to make sure the compiler doesn't align internal fields properly so the CPU does not need to handle it at the hardware level during execution. In this day and age, it's better to let the compiler take care of things for you.

If you'd really prefer this struct packing (as you said, in a network transmission scenario), I'll need further information to determine where the issue lies. Perhaps attempt to change `@property (nonatomic) Foo foo;` to `@property (nonatomic) NSValue *foo;` and then box it and unbox it yourself? This way, the exception/error will be in your application's domain.

Comment: "In this day and age, it's better to let the compiler take care of things for you." — Unfortunately I can't ;). I am getting/sending these structs from/to network, so they should be finely packed to match network protocol...

Comment: @ivanzoid Just because that's the data structure used on *the wire* doesn't mean you need to use that structure within your program.  You should be using marshalling to convert from internal to external representation, especially if you care about *endianness* (which you will when porting to a big-endian system).

Comment: @trojanfoe that would add much more work for me :D and luckily our network protocol endianness matches iOS endianness (so, little-endian)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible with properties, but if it is I don't think you're using the right syntax.

Have you tried changing

```
id boo = [obj valueForKey:@"foo"];
```

to read

```
Foo boo = obj.foo;
```

?

Foo is not nor never will be an `id`. `valueForKey:` returns id, and the runtime might be barfing trying to squeeze `struct Foo` into an `NSValue`.

If you need to use `valueForKey:` for some reason, your accesses need to look like.

```
Foo myFoo = FooFactory();
Object *myObj = [Object new];
[myObj setValue:@( myFoo ) forKey:@"foo"];

Foo myFooOut;
[[myObj valueForKey:@"foo"] getValue:&myFooOut];
//I bet `getValue:` is where things are barfing.
```

In this case, if `NSValue`'s machinery indeed can't handle the packed struct, you just have to write the accessors the old fashioned way: `-<key>` and -set:`.

**PS: Never name a class "Object",** there actually is an `Object` in some SDKs that `NSObject` inherits from. I assume that's just in your example.

Comment: "I bet `getValue:` is where things are barfing." — nope, I really even don't touch the object returned from `valueForKey:`. I've updated the code, now it is complete code to reproduce the crash (`valueForKey:` part may be called from `viewDidLoad` in template iOS project).